# Token invalid: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am learning how to use NodeJS, and while following an online tutorial I incurred in the error in the title.

I am using the latest version of NodeJS, and the jsonwebtoken authentication.

This is how I generate the token:

```
 router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // Check if username was provided
    if (!req.body.username) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No username was provided'
      }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Check if password was provided
      if (!req.body.password) {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'No password was provided.'
        }); // Return error
      } else {
        // Check if username exists in database
        User.findOne({
          username: req.body.username.toLowerCase()
        }, (err, user) => {
          // Check if error was found
          if (err) {
            res.json({
              success: false,
              message: err
            }); // Return error
          } else {
            // Check if username was found
            if (!user) {
              res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'Username not found.'
              }); // Return error
            } else {
              const validPassword = User.comparePassword(req.body.password, user.password); // Compare password provided to password in database
              // Check if password is a match
              if (!validPassword) {
                res.json({
                  success: false,
                  message: 'Password invalid'
                }); // Return error
              } else {
                const token = jwt.sign({
                  userId: user._id
                }, 'goodsecret', {
                  expiresIn: '24h'
                }); // Create a token for client
                res.json({
                  success: true,
                  message: 'Success!',
                  token: token,
                  user: {
                    username: user.username
                  }
                }); // Return success and token to frontend
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

And here how I evaluate it:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

/* ================================================
  MIDDLEWARE - Used to grab user's token from headers
  ================================================ */
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization; // Create token found in headers
    // Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided'
      }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Verify the token is valid
      console.log(token);
      jwt.verify(token, 'goodsecret', (err, decoded) => {
        // Check if error is expired or invalid
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Token invalid: ' + err
          }); // Return error for token validation
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded; // Create global variable to use in any request beyond
          next(); // Exit middleware
        }
      });
    }
  });

  /* ===============================================================
     Route to get user's profile data
  =============================================================== */
  router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    // Search for user in database
    User.findOne({
      _id: req.decoded.userId
    }).select('username email').exec((err, user) => {
      // Check if error connecting
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          success: false,
          message: err
        }); // Return error
      } else {
        // Check if user was found in database
        if (!user) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'User not found'
          }); // Return error, user was not found in db
        } else {
          res.json({
            success: true,
            user: user
          }); // Return success, send user object to frontend for profile
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Whenever I try to generate a request from HttpRequester, sending the token, I get the error in the title. The token I am sending is

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI1OWRlMTYzNTMwOWY2NDM1YjBjOWRmM2UiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDc3NDMzODYsImV4cCI6MTUwNzgyOTc4Nn0.uJwpYN7IHYg_lmCVCpFg-zfo0QVPglEvWHs7SD9cPkg

and on https://jwt.io/ it works fine, using the secret 'goodsecret' as in the code. What am I missing?

[image] This is a screen on how I am generating requests.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you check is token received are exactly the same as thesent?